# TypeScript: referencing resig's extend

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to reference existing code that uses Resig's 'extend', but i'm getting a bunch of errors

------ test.ts --------

```
/// <reference path="myclass.js" />
var m = new MyClass (3);
```

------ myclass.js --------

```
/// <reference path="class.js" />

var MyClass = Class.extend({

    init: function (i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    },
})
```

------ class.js --------

```
(copied from http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)
```

errors:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
The name 'Class' does not exist in the current scope
The property 'extend' does not exist on value of type '() => void'
The name 'Class' does not exist in the current scope
```

i realize that eventually i'd want to rewrite the extend-based code to TypeScript, but until then, how do i reference it from new code?

I guess this begs the deeper question - why is it complaining about type errors in existing javascript code?

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript generally can't infer types from external JavaScript code.

You'll need to declare the shape of the 'extend' code you're calling into so that TypeScript knows what the shape of the type is:

```
declare class Class {
    static extend(body: any);
}
```

You can either put that in your source file directly (if you just have a single-file project), or more properly, in a '.d.ts' file which you reference from your source files.

Comment: I'm confused. if I add <reference path="foo.js/> tags in my .ts files I get errors in Visual Studio's 'Error List' window, so it's at least attempting to parse it. Are you saying that TypeScript can't infer those types, but will generate errors for them anyway? I guess I'm not sure what the interop story is here. If I have to write .d.ts files anyway, why does it bother parsing the .js files?

Comment: You'll still see inferred types for things like functions and variables, so there are use cases for referencing a .js that don't require writing a .d.ts file.

Comment: right, but my point is that it's not useful IMO to infer errors from things that you're not completely inferring. the current behavior means that it's impossible to reference existing code, in general.